# JavaScript open link in new tab instead of popup

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know that this is a similar question to many others, but the problem is that no solution helps.

I am trying to open a link in a new tab after the click on the button. The problem is that I always get the popup instead of new tab. Here's what I've tried so far:

```
var a = document.createElement("a");
a.target = "_blank";
a.href = url;
a.click();
```

Simple window.open doesn't work either:

```
window.open(url, '_blank');
```

Also I tried every solution from:

[Open a URL in a new tab (and not a new window) using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4907843/open-a-url-in-a-new-tab-and-not-a-new-window-using-javascript)

Any more ideas?

Comment: "Nothing an author can do can choose to open in a new tab instead of a new window. It is a user preference."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can force the `target="_blank"` onto an `<a>` by doing this:

```
$('.link-tag').click(function() {
    $(this).attr('target', '_blank');
});
```

This could work in some browsers, but as a commenter said, if the user's preference is set to open in `X`, then it will not be able to force it to open in `Y`.

Comment: Just wanted to make sure, I guess the only way is to not run it from JS itself, but parse some HTML and make a href element with _blank in it?

Comment: @The50 You can do the `_blank` either way, but if a user's preference is to open it in a certain way, you can't force the behavior. Their preferences will override your script or markup.

Comment: how is that any different than above?